# Change Icon Marker Color in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How do change the color of icon markers in Google Maps?

Example:

```
var icon = {
      url: 'custom.svg', // url

}

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: p[1], lng: p[2]},
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
});
```

Inside `var icon`  I tried to fill color and color, but it did not change the color of the icon map marker.  Does anybody know how to change the color?

Comment: Can you use a [SVG Symbol](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#symbols) with your "custom.svg" path?  They support dynamic colors.

Answer (score -1):

Use following code -

```
 let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    icon: {
      url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png"
    }
  });
```